# Looking for command for run dialog/prompt to open current user's directory

Tags: windows-7, windows, run-dialog

From command prompt, if I type the command:

```
start .
```

Then it simply opens the current user's directory **C:\Users<current user name>** in Windows 7. But this command doesn't work from Windows run prompt. Can someone help me with that command if it exists to open current user's directory directly from the run prompt? Currently I've to open command prompt first, then I've to type this command to open the desired directory in windows explorer.

**Update**: I realized that **start .** command from command prompt doesn't open the user's home profile directory always. It happens only if your current working directory in the shell prompt is same as current user's home profile directory. So, had I been in **D:\** in my shell prompt then it would have opened **D:\** in the explorer in place of **C:\users<current user name>**

Comment: `start` is a `cmd` internal command, and internals can be run only by calling `cmd` to execute them, as in `cmd /c start .` or `cmd /c md NewDir`.

Comment: @AFH : Your answer is exactly right.  You, therefore, deserve to get credit.  Put your information into an answer, instead of a comment.  Then RBT should accept your answer, and you might get other up-votes too.  (I would have upvoted it if I saw it.)

Comment: Deleted my answer. As rightly suggested by @TOOGAM, @AFH deserves the credit. The required command to be run from Run dialog/prompt turned out to be - `cmd /c start .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use environment variable `%USERPROFILE%` instead?
[image: User Profile]

There is no need to start any process (`CMD.EXE` or any) just to open user's default folder.

Comment: First of all, actually my initial assumption that `start .` command when executed from command prompt opens user's profile directory was *wrong*. `start .` command simply opens the current shell path (current working directory) in explorer. Coincidentally, when you open command prompt from run prompt, then by default it opens current user's home profile directory. and I was running `start .` command right there. Hence I got the wrong understanding about `start .` command.

Comment: Yes. This is *the* answer. In fact later on, I had myself explored another command `%homepath%` from run prompt which does the same thing. But, never cared to come back to this post. I'm not sure why there are two environment variables which point to the same directory i.e. current user's profile directory.

Answer (score 2):

The `start` command is internal to `cmd`. When you type a command in `cmd`, it will be either:

- an executable program (usually `.exe`, but sometimes with other extensions);
- a batch file (`.bat` or `.cmd`); or
- an internal command, handled within the `cmd` code itself.

These are all handled differently by Explorer and the Windows run command (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>):-

- An executable file is recognised as such and run immediately.
- A batch file's extension is recognised as linked to `cmd`, which is scheduled to run it.
- Windows doesn't recognise the internal commands of `cmd` (or any other interactive program), so typing one of these in the run command box will give a "cannot find" error.

The `cmd` internal commands *can* be executed from the run box, but you need to tell Windows to run `cmd` explicitly. For your command you would type:

```
cmd /c start .
```

Note that this will use the current directory for the run command environment, not your directory in `cmd`, which by default starts in your home directory.

Most of the commands in the `cmd` help list are internal, though a few, such as `find`, `sort` and `diskpart` are external programs (`find.exe`, etc), so there is no need to precede these with `cmd /c` in the run box: Windows will recognise them as command-line utilities and create a command shell in which to run them.

Whenever `cmd` is scheduled to run a command (explicitly or explicitly), it will be short-lived unless the command interacts with the user, though any other programs launched during its execution may persist (as with the `start` command).

Comment: Very thorough explanation @AFH. Loved it! Just curious about one more thing which is environment variables. How run dialog is able to open predefined paths pointed by environment variables like %programdata%, %appdata%, %windir%, %programfiles% etc? Does here also the run dialog uses a command shell internally before it can open the locations (pointed by these environment variables) in an explorer window ?

Comment: No, there is no command shell involved. The environment variables which are defined in Windows (`Control Panel` -> `System` -> `Advanced system settings` -> `Environment Variables...`) are substituted in the Windows run box, in both the command path and its parameters, similarly to `cmd`; the same is true when you type a path in Explorer. You will also find numerous instances of environment variables in paths defined in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

To make good an omission in (almost exhaustive) [AFH's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1147814/376602): in a Windows Run dialog (invoked by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>), a full stop `.` would work exactly as advised `cmd /c start .`

However, I didn't tested exact behaviour of using `.` in case that `cmd`  and `cmd /D` default to different working directory i.e. if the latter is changed by an AutoRun command from registry; for details see `cmd /?`.

Comment: I agree that `.` has the same effect as `cmd /c start .`, but it doesn't work in the same way. The same is true if you replace `.` by any other directory. But the point of the question was not how to start Explorer in a specific directory, but why some `cmd` commands don't work from the Windows run box.